# JS - conversion of non breakable space &nbsp

Tags: javascript, html

I'm reading out a text from an HTML element and saving it in an JS array, but if the user puts in more then one empty space it is converted into a non breakable space symbol. Later on if I read out the array it prints out "&nbsp" instead of an empty space. How can I detect an empty space?

```
&nbsp  //instead of an empty space
```

I tried replace, but it does not work:

```
myText.replace(/(&nbsp;)*/g," ")
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  In HTML multiple consecutive spaces are rendered as a single space so if you want multiple spaces to actually show, then `&nbsp;` is used.

Comment: The user has got an empty text box, if he submits empty spaces, these are converted to &nbsp

Comment: why can't you just replace all `&nbsp;` occurrences with spaces?

Comment: You need to show the code that does this.

Comment: @daisy It's odd that they are automatically converted to `&nbsp;`. Maybe some library is doing it?

Comment: @Uby I tried replace, but it does not work:

myText.replace(/(&nbsp;)*/g," ")

Comment: @daisy try with `myText.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ')`

Comment: @Uby thank you, this works, what does the /g stand for?

Comment: `g` modifier perform a global match (ie: it doesn't stop after first match), so it's useful when you need to replace all occurrences of a string

Comment: @Uby in order to convert it back I then tried myText.replace(/' '/g, '&nbsp;') but here it only works one time, how can I get all ' ' ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regex notation table for whitespace

```
\x20 – standard space ‘\s’
\xC2\xA0 – ‘&nbsp;’
\x0D -  ‘\r’
\x0A – new Line or ‘\n’
\x09 – tab or ‘\t’
```

JS table notation :

```
String.fromCharCode(160) - &nbsp;
```

Now use it for replacing all your characters, add more if you want to remove newline or carriage return

```
var re = '/(\xC2\xA0/|&nbsp;)';
x = x.replace(re, ' ');
```

you can also use

```
var re = '/(\xC2\xA0/|&nbsp;)';
x = x.replace(re, String.fromCharCode(160));
```

Try this tool to test more Regular expression www.rubular.com

Comment: You can also use $(selector).html() to fetch data along with all space if you are using jquery.

Comment: `var tmp = document.createElement('div');
tmp.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
var nonBreakableSpaceChar = tmp.innerText;`